# Webpack 5 - Scss relative urls won't load images

Tags: javascript, sass, webpack-5

I have my scss and my images in folders at the same level.

*File structure*

```
styles
  app.scss
images
  my-image.jpg
```

Am trying to import my image like so

*app.scss*

```
body {
  background: url(../images/my-image.jpg);
}
```

I have a simple webpack configuration to load scss and images.

*webpack.config.js*

```js
const path = require("path");

module.exports = {
  entry: "./resources/index.js",
  resolve: {
    alias: {
      resource: path.resolve(__dirname, "resources/images"),
    },
  },
  output: {
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, "dist"),
    publicPath: "/dist",
    filename: "main.js",
    assetModuleFilename: "[name][ext][query]",
    clean: true,
  },
  mode: "production",
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.js$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        use: {
          loader: "babel-loader",
        },
      },
      {
        test: /\.scss$/,
        use: ["style-loader", "css-loader", "sass-loader"],
      },
      {
        test: /\.(png|jpg)/,
        type: "asset",
      },
    ],
  },
};
```

Later on I tried to use [resolve-url-loader](https://www.npmjs.com/package/resolve-url-loader) between css-loader and scss-loader which seemed promising. But also to no avail.

The build isn't throwing any errors. But the page doesn't open the image.

Thank you for any help you give me my bros and bronettes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

At the end the problem with the images was simply in the **publicPath** on the web.config.js file.

Changing it from `dist/` to `/dist` did the job.

```js
const path = require("path");

module.exports = {
  ...
  output: {
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, "dist"),
    publicPath: "dist/", //This is where the issue was
    filename: "main.js",
    assetModuleFilename: "[name][ext][query]",
    clean: true,
  },
  ...
};
```

Let this be a warning for all ye who enter webpack.